# Unique identifiers for the same type of object in the same request

Tags: mysql

This question is about your opinion and common approach for relational databases. **So please, do not vote me down. I really need to solve this problem.**. I remove this question once I meet the answer.

I have a response from my server sth like this:

```
"groups":[  
              {  
                 "id":"ea369ff6-cbc3-44b6-8eb6-b79e8db0145c",
                 "ingredients":[  
                    {  
                       "id":"f5126c1f-11a7-5ce5-a717-c6c86483058e",
                       "name":"First",
                       "position":1
                    },
                    {  
                       "id":"dfcf217e-53dd-b06c-9f2b-084f8180ba1a",
                       "name":"Second",
                       "position":2
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {  
                 "id":"0fa91ada-1fe4-4d6d-b772-caae44758848",
                 "position":2,
                 "ingredients":[  
                    {  
                       "id":"9cacade2-92fe-bd5c-c84c-7c5fe36c8a5e",
                       "name":"Third",
                       "position":1
                    },
                    {  
                       "id":"f5126c1f-11a7-5ce5-a717-c6c86483058e",
                       "name":"First",
                       "position":2
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
```

- Here are two `groups`. Each of them has unique id.
- Every `group` has some `ingredients`. They are the same type
- Every group has ingredient with name `First`. This ingredient has **the same** `id` in every group, which means, it is the same object.

**but**

`First` ingredient has different values of `position` depending on where it is located.

**The question is:**

Should they have the same `id` while they are not the same? What is good approach for this problem? I need simple, quick and clarified answer.

Doesnt id mean that this is unique along with the same type of object? What If I need to save it to core data or other persistent store on device?

Very thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Normalizing this will result in three tables with an many:many relation, the columns in parens () indicate the logical Primary Key:

*groups: (group_id)*

*ingredients: (ingredient_id), name*

*ingredients_per_group: (group_id, ingredient_id), position*

This is the junction table between groups and ingredients, the *position* is just an attribute of the ingredient in this specific group.

If an ingredient could be used many times in the same recipe but in different positions, (say use some butter in step 2 but also in step 17), then the PK of *ingredients_per_group* should be *(group_id, ingredient_id, position)*.

It's like an ingredient for a receipt, the same ingredient can/will be used in multiple receipts, but in different amounts or in a different order.